# Removing dynamically created component causes error

Tags: apache-flex, events

I have problem with casting custom event currentTarget to component. When I'm trying to removeElement from its parent container i get error. What's the deal?

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.events::FlexEvent@8811c41 to com.modultek.pis.itemmachine.search.events.SortEvent.

private function sortSelection_removeHandler(event:SortEvent):void
{
            var sortSelection:SortSelection = event.currentTarget as SortSelection;
            this.removeElement(sortSelection);
}
```

Component will be removed but I get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is not in the `var sortSelection:SortSelection = event.currentTarget as SortSelection;` line at all.

Read the Error message carefully. It tells you that there is an invalid cast from `FlexEvent` to `SortEvent`, which happens on

```
private function sortSelection_removeHandler(event:SortEvent):void
```

Change `event:SortEvent` in the function signature to `event:FlexEvent` or `event:Event`

Comment: Okay. If i need to add data to event, then FlexEvent does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I didn't have event declaration on my dispatching class.

```
[Event(name="remove" , type=".....search.events.SortEvent")]
```